# Google Assist Integration - Local SDK without cloud functionality

Tags: iot

I have a smart home device and am getting it integrated with Google home.

My question is regarding the Local sdk option. Can I skip the cloud integration path and only get a local fulfillment going? By local fulfillment I mean that the users can only say "ok google open the blinds", when they are connected to the same wifi network as the smart device.
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Local execution will definitely make lifecycle management easier for you and it will be more or less the same as the cloud execution.

First, you need to prepare your cloud instance to support location execution.
You need to configure how SYNC's intent should respond. This will be set in the "Device Config" option. More information can be easily found online.

The Google home or nest device will send the command directly to the local network, bypassing the cloud fulfillment. And hence this will be faster.
Also, to be on the safer side assistant will fallback to your cloud server for fulfillment if command execution is not completed locally.

For more information, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=189&v=aaaUSeQGLAA&feature=emb_title&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers) should help.

Thank you!